# How can I make a pyramid based on alphabet?

Tags: javascript, alphabet

So how can I make multiply alphabet letters? I'm using an array with strings and I want to multiply them by their index.

```
A
BB
CCC
DDDD
EEEEE
```

etc.

```
<script>
    window.onload = start;
    var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
                   "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
                   21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26];

    function start() {
        document.getElementById("randomize").onclick = execute;
    }

    function execute() {
        for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j <= numbers.length; j++) {
                var product = numbers.length * letters[i];
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<li>" + letters[i] + "</li>";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And what's the problem you're having?

Comment: [String.prototype.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @EvanKnowles My output only shows the alphabet a single time and not multiplying them so: 
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z

Comment: @SuzdarZeni Kindly check out the snippet in my answer. Refresh the page and click on the Run Snippet. Tell me if it works.

Comment: `letters.map( (letter, idx) => letter.repeat( idx + 1 ) ).join("\n")` https://jsfiddle.net/ukqjsfqc/

Comment: @Soolie Omg thank you! it works now as intended!

Comment: @Soolie Noted !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did almost everything perfect, except, you need to get the `numbers[i]` value and not the length.

```js
window.onload = start;

var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
               "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
               21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26];

function start() {
  document.getElementById("randomize").onclick = execute;
}


function execute() {
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    var product = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < numbers[i]; j++)
      product += letters[i];
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<li>" + product + "</li>";
  }
}
```

```css
li {font-family: 'Consolas', monospace;}
```

```html
<button id="randomize">Randomize</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: `j < numbers[i]` or start with `j = 1`, then it's "perfect" :)

Comment: @xander Thanks. I am updating. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

```
for(var i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(65 + i).repeat(i + 1));
}
```

gives you

```
A
BB
CCC
...
```

An even shorter one:

```
var i = 0;
while(i++ < 26) console.log(String.fromCharCode(64 + i).repeat(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

in a oneliner (somewhath):

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<li>" + 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("").map(
         x => "".padStart(x.charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0) + 1, x)
    ).join("</li>\n<li>") + "</li>"
```

Where:

- `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("")` create an array from a string
- `x => "".padStart(x.charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0) + 1, x)` create a string for a character `x`
- [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) create a string with the desired length
- length is based on his position in the alphabet `x.charCodeAt(0) - "A".charCodeAt(0) + 1` see [String.charCodeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)
- the external join create a list with the calculated strings